# Como faço para imprimir um item específico do JSON em PHP?

Tags: php, json, composer

```
<?php
        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

        $accessToken = "----------------------------";


        use TotalVoice\Client as TotalVoiceClient;

        $client = new TotalVoiceClient($accessToken);

        $response = $client->perfil->consultaSaldo();

        echo $response->getContent(); // {}

?>
```

o retorno

{"status":200,"sucesso":true,"motivo":0,"mensagem":"saldo atual","dados":{"saldo":2.47}}

mas eu quero pegar só o saldo:2.47

Answer (score 0):

Solucão rápida:

```
<?php 

    $retorno='{"status":200,"sucesso":true,"motivo":0,"mensagem":"saldo atual","dados":{"saldo":2.47}}';

    $json=json_decode($retorno);
    var_dump($json);

    echo $json->dados->saldo;

    ?>
```

Peguei o resultado do json, chamei a função `json_decode` para transformar o retorno do json em um `array`, usei um `var_dump` só para visualizar a sequencia da array e depois fiz a sequencia de acesso. Olhando pelo `var_dump` você entenderá quando a lógica utilizada na linha `$json->dados->saldo;`

Answer (score -1):

```
        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

        $accessToken = "----------------------------";


        use TotalVoice\Client as TotalVoiceClient;

        $client = new TotalVoiceClient($accessToken);

        $response = $client->perfil->consultaSaldo();

        $conteudo = $response->getContent();
        $json = json_decode($conteudo);
        echo "SALDO: ". $json->dados->saldo;  

?>
```